# can I display content when double braces is inside double braces?

Tags: angularjs

I have this {{a[2][ {{a[2].length}} ]}} condition and I want to display content from the model. Can I use something like that  double braces inside double braces?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the inner double braces is ok:

```
{{a[2][a[2].length - 1]}}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/sbEsNQ?p=preview

BTW, you should change a[2].length to a[2].length - 1, otherwise you will always visit an undefined value.

Comment: Yes, it should be an nested array. What's your question? BTW, I have updated the answer in plnkr.

Comment: I solved with this {{a[2][a[2].length-1]}} thank you very much for https://plnkr.co/edit/sbEsNQ?p=preview @huan feng

Comment: np, if it solves your problem, please mark it as the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Can I use something like that double braces inside double braces? no you cannot use nested braces in angular.

---

**.:: Solution ::.**

instead of *{{a[2][ {{a[2].length}} ]}}* try this:

create a function whith a[2] as input parameter, then return everything you want. for example:

```
function sample(input){
    return input[input.length]
}
```

inside your html put {{sample(a[2])}}